# Python: Pick String items

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

Has to be done in python 2.7, because of the assignment program.

Write a function def get_strings(mixed_list):, which returns a new list with all the string type items in the mixedList given as an argument. The order of the string items must match the original list. For example, if called with a list like this...

```
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', True, 'e']
```

The function should return a list like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'e']
```

```
l = []
s = string.ascii_letters
for i in range(random.randint(15,25)):
   r = random.randint(0,2)
   if r == 0:
     ind = random.randint(0, len(s) -1 )
     l.append(s[ind : ind + random.randint(1, 4) ])
   elif r == 1:
      l.append(random.randint(-50,50))
   else:
      l.append(random.choice([True, False, 1.0 / random.randint(1, 10) ]))

print ("Whole list:", l)
print ("Strings only:" , get_strings(l))

import random
```

Comment: Why on earth does an instructor demand students use python 2? It is uneducational, cruel, and irresposible.

Comment: @j1-lee We use a site called Ville, that works on Python 2... No idea why.. No one likes this :)

Comment: I feel you (sigh). Can't help you because I have no experience with python 2, but good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Can you give any explanation to the code you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def get_strings(mixed_list):
    return [i for i in mixed_list if isinstance(i, str)]
```

For Python 2.7 as @Bernana suggested:

```
def get_strings(mixed_list):
    return [i for i in mixed_list if isinstance(i, basestring)]
```

Comment: Ty, a lot.:) The first one worked, oddly when/if it shouldn't have worked on 2.7. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

in python2.7 `isinstance` would not work with `str` but with `basestring`.

it should look like:

```
    lst = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', True, 'e']
    l = []
    print([x for x in lst if isinstance(x, basestring)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) along with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
def get_strings(mixed_list):
    return [x for x in mixed_list if isinstance(x, str)]

l = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', True, 'e']
print ("Whole list:", l)
print ("Strings only:" , get_strings(l))
```

**Output:**

```
Whole list: [1, 'a', 2, 'b', True, 'e']
Strings only: ['a', 'b', 'e']
```